# How do I avoid chain refencing and singletons, when communicating between classes?

Tags: design-patterns

I have the class "GameWorld", which has a "GameManager" variable. The "GameWorld" also have a **"PipeManager"** variable, which in turn has a **"PipePair"** variable, which in turn has a **"Pipe"** variable.

How can I easily communicate between "GameManager" and "Pipe"?
[image: Want to send info]

I know I can send a "GameManager" reference to "PipeManager", which in turn sends the "GameManager" reference to "PipePair", which in turn sends the "GameManager" reference to "Pipe". But it becomes a bit annoying if the chain is long and I have to send multiple different references.
[image: chain referencing]

I also know that I can use a singleton, but I have had problems with memory leaks, when I use them.
[image: singleton]

Is there a more easy way to directly communicate between classes, without sending references in chains and using singletons?

Comment: Design questions are usually Opinion Based. When tagging [C++] you need to have some reference to the language in the question, the above question could apply to almost any computer language.

Comment: If you get memory leaks for using singletons, you're doing something really, really wrong. Note that not cleaning up on shutdown may be diagnosed as a mem leak, but it isn't actually. That said, singletons are considered an antipattern, because they are effectively globals with pretty much all implied problems they cause. So, question, why can't you pass a reference (e.g. as `shared_ptr`) to the code that needs it?

Comment: One Alternate is to make GameManager observable to Pipe i.e. whenever Pipe changes it notifies to all its observer. For more detail you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: @RichardCritten the general problem could be language-agnostic, but I can very well envision a C++ solution relying on features that don't exist in other languages.

Comment: @smalik Thanks for the information, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: @Quentin the OP does not say in the question that a C++ answer is wanted. I don't think that we can infer that just from a tag.

Comment: This is really hard to reason about, since we don't know any multiplicities and whether the relationships are a aggregation or composition relationship, or none of those.